# CodeIgniter Search by string using get

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I am stuck with writing View for my code igniter search form which need to use get..

I currently have this

Controller

```
<?php
class Search extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('Search');
    }
    public function doSearch()
{
    $this->load->model("Messages_model");

    if ($this->input->get('search') !== FALSE) {
        $data ['results'] = $this->Messages_model->searchMessages($this->input->get('search'));
    } else {
        $data['results'] = array();
    }

    $this->load->view("Search", $data);
}
```

Model

```
class Messages_model extends CI_Model{
function searchMessages($string){
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE text  LIKE '%$string%'");
    return $query->result();
}
```

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
 </style>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo site_url('Search/doSearch');?>" method = "get">
    <input type="text" name = "keyword"/>
    <input type="submit" value = "Search" />
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me out in getting search string displayed

Comment: Hint: Read about URI Segments https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: Are you actually having a query sting in the url (ie `?search=bob`) or are you wanting the search term to come after the forward slash e.g. `example.com/seach/bob` ?

Comment: Well, what i really need is to be able to type a word in a search form and submit it via get

Comment: Ok, lastly are you using codeigniter 2.* or codeigniter 3.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, go to **application/config/config.php** and find `$config['allow_get_array']` and make sure it's set to `TRUE`.

Then in your controller you would have something like this:

```
public function search()
{
    $this->load->model("Messages_model");

    if ($this->input->get('search') !== FALSE) {
        $data ['results'] = $this->Messages_model->searchMessages($this->input->get('search'));

    } else {
        $data['results'] = array();
    }

    $this->load->view("Search", $data);
}
```

Please note that there isn't any validation happening on the string here so you will need to add your own.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

View file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
    </style>

    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo site_url('search/doSearch'); ?>" method = "get">
            <input type="text" name="keyword" value="<?php echo isset($search_value) ? $search_value : ''?>"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>

        <?php
        if ($search_passed && !empty($results)) {
            foreach ($results as $result) {
                //Code for displaying results
            }
        } elseif ($search_passed && empty($results)) {
            echo 'No results found!';
        }
        ?>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller Method:

public function doSearch()
    {
        $this->load->model("Messages_model");

```
    if ($this->input->get('keyword') !== FALSE) {
        $data ['results'] = $this->Messages_model->searchMessages($this->input->get('keyword'));
        //Uncomment the line below to test
        // echo '<pre>'; print_r($data['results']);die('</pre>');
        $data['search_passed'] = TRUE;
        $data['search_value'] = $this->input->get('keyword');
    } else {
        $data['search_passed'] = FALSE;
        $data['results'] = array();
    }

    $this->load->view("Search", $data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how would you go about writing the view for this? thats my main struggle.. i dont really know how to make it use this function

Comment: Do you know how to make forms?

Comment: Well.. i currently have this...
<form action="<?php echo site_url('');?>" method = "get">
    <input type="text" name = "keyword"/>
    <input type="submit" value = "Search" />
</form>

Comment: `<?php echo site_url('');?>` is going to send the form data to your site's index page. Change `site_url('')` to `site_url('search/view')` as you want the form to submit to the controller/method that is handling the search.

Comment: Thanks again, but i still cannot make it display the search results.. i tried writing foreach, and <?php pring ("Search")?> still no luck

Comment: In that case can you put exactly what you have in your controller and exactly what you have in your view in to your question above and I then I can see why it's not working :)

Comment: Edited, i have also changed my SQL as i realized it didn't work, and renamed my search function

Comment: Thank you for the code, but unfortunately it doesnt find any results..just says no results found... i know my SQL is correct as i tested it..

Comment: After changing to false the problem still remains

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realised that you'd named your input as keyword and not search. The update should work now.

Comment: Perfect thank you very much.. i had to change FALSE TO TRUE back tho.. but works like a charm! thank you again!

Comment: It's alright, the `FALSE` was put in there so that you don't see "No results found" when you first come to the page. Glad I could help!